# Uses-permission for GPS Location

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

What uses-permission should I include to my Android manifest to access the current (GPS)location in my Application (Android Studio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need below permissions

> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
>   android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

fine location will give you access to gps data.

**Updated:**

The documentation for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION states:

> Allows an app to access approximate location derived from network
>   location sources such as cell towers and Wi-Fi

So if you want some additional stuffs you can use this otherwise `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` will work for you.

Comment: Does the OP really need COARSE_LOCATION to get GPS position? If his application must rely on precise location, then I believe coarse location is only a plus.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful. i will go with android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION..

Comment: Yes i need a java code for it to.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636547/looking-for-a-location-uses-permission-java-code